# How to save emails in SharePoint with "to", "from". "date received" etc columns and non-unique document titles?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-email

I'm working on a SharePoint setup for a small legal office. Each legal matter must have all emails saved in a correspondence list specific to that matter (on some transactions this can mean hundreds of emails). Therefore, we need:

1. The ability to save multiple emails with the same document title in SharePoint (eg there may be multiple files named "RE: Agreement Name - Client Name" saved to the list; and
2. Columns in the list to show "Date Received", "Date Sent", "Email From" and "Email To".

Any hints of where to start with this would be massively appreciated. I've already enabled a unique document ID for each document in the SharePoint library and major + minor versioning, if that context helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think your requirements are universal. This is something many companies struggle with.

There are several options:

1. Use one of the many Outlook add-ins to allow users to archive email to SharePoint and extract email metadata such as Date Sent, etc..
   See [here](https://directory.collab365.community/office365-sharepoint/sharepoint-email-management-software/). This option adds the "logic" to Outlook.
2. Use Apps in SharePoint that offer the required funtionality (extract email metadata and generate unique documents)
   see e.g. [here](https://www.slimapplications.com/product/email-manager/) or [here](https://www.slimapplications.com/product/explorer/)
   The logic is added to SharePoint (SharePoint Online or on-premise) and works on mac OS and Windows clients.
3. Develop your own solution
   Do not underestimate the complexity. The msg file format is a binary format. If you have eml emails then things become simpler.
4. Use Power Automate to extract the email metadata and then also make sure the uploaded email has a unique name. Search forums for examples. This basically works in the "background".

Paul

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'd like to learn how to develop my own solution here. Would you be able to explain what I'd need to get started to learn that?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you'll need to build a VSTO add-in which will work on native Outlook applications and a web add-in to target OWA and OSX users.

- VSTO: you can create a C# or VB solution in Visual studio and start with an Outlook Add-In project/Template. The main thing to figure out is how will you authenticate the user from Outlook to SharePoint. Rest everything is exposed by the Outlook Object Model. For this project you need to have knowledge of CSOM and OOM. (reference https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook)
- Web Add-In: This can be created in Visual studio as a web add-in project OR you can use the new SPFx framework (node.js based). The main thing to remember is that web add-in only support client side code i.e. HTML, CSS and JS. For this project you need to have knowledge of JSOM/REST API and Outlook JS API (Office.js). (reference https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53636.sharepoint-framework-develop-outlook-add-ins.aspx)

You'll need to consider cost vs benefit of developing such a solution as there is a lot of development involved from my experience. There are a few third-party solutions that might be cheaper to run than spend time on developing this; as an example - https://konnectemail.com (Disclaimer - I work as a developer here)